# How to stretch buttons across div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is my App.js file:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className='calculator'>
                <div className='display'>
                    <span>0</span>
                </div>
                <div className='operators'>
                    <Keyboard />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My index.css file:

```
:root{
--light: #cdd9e7;
--dark: #000000;
--primary: #83fffc;
--secondary: #ff5740;
--border: #9ca8b5;
--light2: #ff8b6c;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

.App {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 300;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.calculator {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
    background-color: var(--light);
    border-radius: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 450px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.display {
    padding: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    font-size: 24px;
    border-color: #9ca8b5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 16px;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

button {
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: medium;
    border-radius: 2px;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 16px;
}

button :hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.operators {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.operators button{
    flex: auto;
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    font-weight: 24px;
    border-radius: 24px;
    margin: 6px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}
```

And my Keyboard.jsx file

```
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button name="Clear" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>Clear</button>
            <button name="+/-" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>+/-</button>
            <button name="%" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>%</button>
            <button name="/" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>/</button><br />


            <button name="7" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>7</button>
            <button name="8" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>8</button>
            <button name="9" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>9</button>
            <button name="x" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>x</button><br />


            <button name="4" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>4</button>
            <button name="5" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>5</button>
            <button name="6" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>6</button>
            <button name="-" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>-</button><br />

            <button name="1" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>1</button>
            <button name="2" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>2</button>
            <button name="3" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>3</button>
            <button name="+" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>4</button><br />


            <button name="0" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>0</button>
            <button name="." onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>.</button>
            <button name="=" onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e.target.name)}>=</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm working on a calculator app. It's the first React app I've tried to develop on my own. I want the buttons to be organized the same way as the calculator app on MacBooks. Right now, they're all squished towards the center. I've tried using display: flex, using the classname "grid-container" in my Keyboard component, and adding a width: 100% property to the button style. Any suggestions on how to align these buttons and stretch them out the way I want would be appreciated. The link to my work so far is right [here](https://github.com/jsrosser73/Calculator-Test)[image]

Comment: Hi! Rather than link to code (which doesn't appear to be working), you'll get more help if you create a minimal reproducible example and include it in your question.  There's more advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: For your use case, I would take a look into [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) since you're concerned about maintaining a 2d layout.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.